# "undefined: hmac.Equal" error while hmac.New in the line before this works fine

Tags: go, hmac

I am developing a web server in go,
at the top I have

```
import ("net/http"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/hex"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/hmac"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "github.com/crowdmob/goamz/aws"
    "github.com/crowdmob/goamz/dynamodb"
)
```

later I have

```
func singSomething(someid string) string {
mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    mac.Write([]byte(id))
    b := mac.Sum(nil)
return hex.EncodeToString(b)
}

func validateSignature(id, signature string) bool {
mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    mac.Write([]byte(id))
    expectedMAC := mac.Sum(nil)
    signatureMAC, err := hex.DecodeString(signature)
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("PROBLEM IN DECODING HUH!")
    return false
    }
return hmac.Equal(expectedMAC,signatureMAC)
```

}

I get this error when I issue `go run CSServer`
 `/CSServer.go:54: undefined: hmac.Equal`

Why? What is going on? How come `hmac.New` is fine but `hmac.Equals` is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what the problem was,
but after striping down the code and puting it in play.golang.org and seeing that it works fine there bun not on my machine, I checked and the my version, it was `go1.0.3` I installed the latest `go1.1.2 darwin/amd64` and problem solved, very weird.

Comment: Go 1.0.3 Didn't have hmac.Equal - see [the release notes](http://golang.org/doc/go1.1#minor_library_changes). I filed [Issue 5778](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5778) about this being missing from the documentation in general.

Answer (score 0):

Please post minimal, but complete programs when asking. Without that, the only thing I can provide is an example which compiles w/o trouble, ie. the undefined `hmac.Equal` doesn't demonstrate. There must be some problem elsewhere in the code you didn't show.

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/hmac"
        "crypto/sha256"
        "encoding/hex"
        "fmt"
)

func singSomething(someid string) string {
        mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte{})
        mac.Write([]byte(someid))
        b := mac.Sum(nil)
        return hex.EncodeToString(b)
}

func validateSignature(id, signature string) bool {
        mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte{})
        mac.Write([]byte(id))
        expectedMAC := mac.Sum(nil)
        signatureMAC, err := hex.DecodeString(signature)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("PROBLEM IN DECODING HUH!")
                return false
        }
        return hmac.Equal(expectedMAC, signatureMAC)
}

func main() {}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SAf6DNS1cT)